# Regex that will get dimensions from string

Tags: regex, dimensions

I'm having a heck of a time finding a regex that will pull dimensions from a string.

Here is what I have so far, its not really doing what I want:

```
((\d+\s*(\d+\d+|\d+)*)\s*[xX]\s*(\d+\s*(\d+\d+|\d+)*)\s*[xX]\s*(\d+\s*(\d+\d+|\d+)*)|(\d+\s*(\d+\d+|\d+)*)\s*[xX]\s*(\d+\s*(\d+\d+|\d+)*)| (\d+\s*(\d+\d+|\d+)*))
```

Here are some examples of what it pulls (bolded):

-16" x **1476**' **80** GA. EQ Ultra-Premium Hand Wrap - Use as replacement for **18**" x **1500**' **80** Gauge (4/Case)
-**48 x 60**" Corrugated Sheet (250/Bale)
-MP  Die Cut Divider **25 7**/ **8 x 19 3**/4  **1000**/bale
-Part "B" (3"x**3x 1**/2" charcoal foam) only - extra pieces

I'm looking for it grab do the following:

-**16" x 1476**' 80 GA. EQ Ultra-Premium Hand Wrap - Use as replacement for **18" x 1500**' 80 Gauge (4/Case)
-**48 x 60**" Corrugated Sheet (250/Bale)
-MP  Die Cut Divider **25 7/8 x 19 3/4** 1000/bale
-Part "B" (**3"x3 x 1/2"** charcoal foam) only - extra pieces

Notice the regex is not catching the lower part of the fraction because of the "/", also if an inch symbol (i.e. ") is between that dimension and another number it won't grab the first number, you can see that in the first example.

Once I have this regex working, I can strip out the inch and foot symbols (i.e. " and '), and break each number down into each dimension. Just trying to pull the initial dimension numbers first.

Thanks so much if you have any input.

Comment: `3"x3 x 1/2"` How does that fit in? If the x *in the middle of a number* is a requirement, it makes this a lot more difficult.

Comment: @aliteralmind: I believe it's 3D (X x Y x Z). Not in the middle of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\d+\s*\d+\s*\/\d+|\d+\s*\/\d+|\d+)["']?(\s*[xX]\s*(\d+\s*\d+\s*\/\d+|\d+\s*\/\d+|\d+)["']?)+
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/RAKldS4hxm)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much for the help, marked you as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the x-in-the-middle-of-the-number thing, and I didn't attempt to get that part, but otherwise, this works:

```
([0-9]+["']?(?: [0-9]+/[0-9]+)? x [0-9]+["']?(?: [0-9]+/[0-9]+)?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/918rDBNLbIrTbpQ7)

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Comment: I'll be sure to bookmark that FAQ page, thanks for that.